# How can i get photo_url from janrain / RPX?

Tags: openid, gmail, photo, janrain, rpx

If somebody visit my site, i would like to extract the photo_url after jainrain / RPX authentication was happend on my site. But photo_url was not sent. I get the openid name, but not the photo address.  I tried it with my gmail account, i put a photo to my profile, and i published it for anybody, but gmail doesn't sent it for me. Why don't work it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, there is solution. I found it [here](http://www.webmonkey.com/2009/11/google_profiles_now_function_as_openids/). If you sign up not with you google account, but your google profile (there is difference) then you will get the profile photo url also.

Answer (score 0):

It's not required for an OpenID Provider to send any information about an authenticated user, even if you request it.

As far as I know Google does not support sending photo urls, though it does support sending names and email addresses.

Comment: And what could i do still this? I would like to present my own gmail image on my own webpage. And maybe my familiars photo. It seems not an impossible demand. I wish set the gmail access right something more sophisticated. There isn't an hidden checkbox for this somewhere in gmail?

Comment: It is so funny, when a site's visitors picture, mostly picture from facebook is aside the page.

Comment: While I can't understand most of what you're trying to say, I'm sure that gmail does not support fetching image urls with OpenID. Anyway, if janrain engage returns empty photo_url, I don't see what you could do to change it.